# How to run rc.local as normal user?

Tags: startup

I have some commends that I wish to be called right after login, including 'startx', and I thought `rc.local` seems a nice place for them, but the problem is that `rc.local` is run as root and I don't want that, obviously I can do something like this:

```
su username -c somecommend-here
```

But I am looking for a way to run the whole 'rc.local' as normal user, or perhaps there is a better place to put my code ?

PS. I am using Ubuntu-mini-remix 1104i386

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK rc.local is executed parallel to login at the end of the boot sequence. I mean, it will be executed even if you don't log in, but you can be logged in ant it could be pending execution.

Comment: @JavierRivera So what would be the solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to launch a command when a user logs in is to create a `.desktop` file for the command and stick it in the `~/.config/autostart` folder. What does the desktop file look like? Here is an example that retrieves the Ask Ubuntu home page with `wget` every time the user logs in:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Name=Launch wget
Comment=Fetches the Ask Ubuntu home page.
Exec=wget http://askubuntu.com/
```

Comment: Does not seem a good idea to launch `startx` (as the OP asked) **after** graphical login.

Comment: @enzotib: There is no mention of a graphical login.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, I believed the user would to start `startx` from `rc.local`. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the differences between /etc/rc.local and a crontab, but I generally make a service account and add the appropriate job. For example: sudo crontab -u p4padmin -e

```
@reboot ~/bin/p4p -d -r ~/var/p4p/cache/foo -p 2020 -t depot:2020 -L ~/var/p4p/log/foo.log
```

You don't have to login for the service to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The linux way is to append your commands to `~/.bashrc` instead of `/etc/rc.local`.

Every user has a `.bashrc` in it's home directory.
This scriptfile is run automatically just after a user logs in.
It is run with the credentials of the user so a `su` command is not needed.

It seems to me that this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is not quite correct, as `.bashrc` is not read when a user logs in using the normal `lightdm`, for example.

Comment: I concluded too fast that the user was using a commandline login instead of a display manager because of the "manual" startx command he mentioned....my bad :-)